# Pytest cov does not generate any report

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, code-coverage, pytest

I'm trying to run a py.test cov for my program, but I still have an information: `testFile.txt sCoverage.py warning: No data was collected.`
even when in the code are still non-tested functions (in my example function diff). Below is the example of the code on which I tested the command `py.test --cov=testcov.py`. I'm using `python 2.7.9`

```
def suma(x,y):
    z = x + y
    return z

def diff(x,y):
    return x-y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = suma(2,3)
    b = diff(7,5)
    print a
    print b

## ------------------------TESTS-----------------------------   
import pytest

def testSuma():
    assert suma(2,3) == 5
```

Can someone explain me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

You haven't said what all your files are named, so I'm not sure of the precise answer. But the argument to `--cov` should be a module name, not a file name.  So instead of `py.test --cov=testcov.py`, you want `py.test --cov=testcov`.

Comment: what if I want to use folder (SRC) instead of module

Answer (score 9):

What worked well for me is:

```
py.test mytests/test_mytest.py --cov='.'
```

Specifying the path, `'.'` in this case, removes unwanted files from the coverage report.

Answer (score 7):

py.test looks for functions that start with `test_`. You should rename your test functions accordingly. To apply coverage you execute `py.test --cov`. If you want a nice HTML report that also shows you which lines are not covered you can use `py.test --cov --cov-report html`.

Answer (score 0):

By default py.test looks for files matching `test_*.py`. You can customize it with [pytest.ini](https://pytest.org/latest/customize.html#confval-python_files)

Btw. According to python style guide [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it should be `test_suma` - but it has no impact on py.test.